# IIIF image processing like iiifhosting.com

Tags: image-processing, iiif

I want to know that is there any existing feature that cantaloupe offer to resize low resolution images to high resolution like iiifhosting.com is doing?

For example, if I have image of 1000x750 and upload it to directory. When i access with cantaloupe end point url like,
{scheme}://{server}{/prefix}/{identifier}/info.json
https://example.org/image-service/abcd1234/info.json

I got width = 1000 and height = 750 of image in json response.

I want to increase that width and height of image to something like 6117x4112.

I am asking this because i am using mirador viewer in my web application and mirador viewer does not zoom in and zoom out low resolution images.

Before that i was using iiifhosting.com now i want to setup my own server.

When i upload images on iiifhosting.com like i have uploaded 1000x750 image on iiifhosting.com and when i access image info.json
{scheme}://{server}{/prefix}/{identifier}/info.json
it gives me width and height of image to higher scale like some greater values 6117x4112. Please let me know how i can achieve that.

Thanks.